# resize with vertical scroll bar in div

Tags: jquery, css, jquery-ui

I have a divs where i applied jquery resize in all directions (n,e,s,w,ne,se,sw,nw), resize cursor is not showing for east direction in IE, when there is vertical scroll bar in div. But this works fine in firefox.

html:

```
    <div id="one" class="moveable first">
      one one one one one one
    </div>
    <div id="two" class="moveable second">
      two two two two two two
    </div>
```

css:

```
.moveable {
  margin: 0px 14px 12px 0;
  float:left;
  background:#FFFFFF;
}

.first{
  width:100px;
}
```

jQuery:

```
var resizehandler = {
  handles: 'n,s,e,w,sw,se,ne,nw'
};

$(".moveable").resizable(resizehandler);
```

[fiddle](http://www.jsfiddle.net/NTy6H/11/)

Answer (score 0):

Add to css:

```
.movable{
  overflow: hidden;
}
```

[jsfiddle](http://www.jsfiddle.net/NTy6H/12/)